# Name cannot be changed on save dialogue

Tags: 20.04, filesystem, gui

Minimum required condition for recreation.

Ubuntu 20.04
kernel 5.15.0-53-generic
Model XPS-13
Chrome 07.0.5304.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)

note that this occurs not just in chrome, but any application that uses the system's save dialogue.

For example, in Google Chrome, I press `Contrl-S` to save a webpage. When doing so, a save dialogue appears for specifying the name and directory of the file.

[image: a filer]

When I press any key to modify the name of a file, a letter is inserted into a search window, rather than changing the actual file name.

[image: Pressed "a" to change the name to a.html]

It occurs in **any web browsers** or software which use this system's default save dialogue for specifying a filename and directory.

I think it's a bug in a filesystem, if someone could teach me where to report this, that would also be great.

Comment: I think you mean the save dialogue. What happens of you left click with the mouse in the given name and highlight the unwanted portion of the given name and replace with what you want?

Comment: It gives me `cut/copy/paste/select all/ etc...`, the usual paste menu.

Comment: yes, that's normal and the way it works. just replace the highlighted text with the filename you want it to be ie overtyping it.

Comment: The bug is that whenever I try to do that by pressing the corresponding character to replace the highlighted section, it automatically types into the search section of the dialogue

Comment: I get the same behaviour with Ubuntu 22.04. Are you using i3-wm by any chance?

Comment: sorry , I don't know any more, I reported a bug in 
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/gtk/+bug/1878076 hope this helps.